# How to remove rounded corners from bootstrap checkbox

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am unable to remove rounded corners from *checkbox* element and unable to change its `shadow` and `background-color`.

Can some on help me to achieve this? 
I tried with:

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 0px;}
```

Comment: Could you post a JSfiddle please?

Comment: Here is my bin http://jsbin.com/boreja/edit?html,output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to style checkbox using CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-checkbox-using-css)

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove default class of checkbox

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="">Option 1</label>
</div>
```